# Captcha needs urgent upgrade

Tags: bug, captcha

I don't bother to log in when switching to data.stackexchange.com for a quick query, but today when I did that I found the following captcha:

[image: Direct site owners to g.co/recaptcha/upgrade]

FWIW, typing in that text does not work for me.

So, developers, please check out https://g.co/recaptcha/upgrade at your earliest convenience.

Comment: Its actually a known issue

Comment: @JourneymanGeek, thanks. I must have mistyped *captcha* when I searched to see whether it had been raised before.